# shell script condition for version number

Tags: shell, conditional-statements

I'm really new to shell script and I would like to check for software version number and set condition upon it.

ex: check if python version > 2.7.0
then
...

I can check for python using this:

```
if [ "$(python -V 2>&1)" ]
then
    pyv="$(python -V 2>&1)"
    echo "$pyv"
fi
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Python's output is not immediately useful:

```
$ python -V
Python 2.7.9
```

The output includes a word, `Python`, and a version number.  Further, because the version number has two decimal points, it is not a valid number.

#### Approach 1: using bc

One approach is to convert the version into a valid decimal number:

```
$ python -V 2>&1 | awk -F'[ .]' '{printf "%s.%s%02.f",$2,$3,$4}'
2.709
```

In this form, version 2.7.10 would become 2.710.  This approach works up through point version of 99.  If you think there is a chance that python will release a point version 100, then we would want to change the format slightly.

We can now compare number using `bc`:

```
$ echo "$(python -V 2>&1 | awk -F'[ .]' '{printf "%s.%s%02.f",$2,$3,$4}') > 2.7" | bc -l
1
$ echo "$(python -V 2>&1 | awk -F'[ .]' '{printf "%s.%s%02.f",$2,$3,$4}') > 2.710" | bc -l
0
```

To use that in an `if` statement:

```
if echo "$(python -V 2>&1 | awk -F'[ .]' '{printf "%s.%s%02.f",$2,$3,$4}') > 2.7" | bc -l | grep -q 1
then
    echo version greater than 2.7
fi
```

If the test is successful, `bc -l` prints a `1` to standard out.  To silently test for the presence of `1`, we use `grep -q 1`.

#### Approach 2: using integer comparison

We use awk to convert the version number to an integer form:

```
$ python -V 2>&1 | awk -F'[ .]' '{printf "%2.f%02.f%02.f",$2,$3,$4}'
 20709
```

Now, we can use standard shell tools to test the version:

```
if [ "$(python -V 2>&1 | awk -F'[ .]' '{printf "%2.f%02.f%02.f",$2,$3,$4}')" -gt 20700 ]
then
   echo version greater than 2.7
fi
```

#### Approach 3: using GNU `sort -V`

GNU sort has a version sorting feature.  To use it, we create input useful for version sorting:

```
$ t="Python 2.7.0"
$ echo "$(python -V 2>&1)"$'\n'"$t" | sort -V -k2,2
Python 2.7.0
Python 2.7.9
```

Now, we sort in ascending order:

```
$ echo "$(python -V 2>&1)"$'\n'"$t" | sort -V -k2,2
Python 2.7.0
Python 2.7.9
```

If the first line is `$t`, that means that the actual python version is newer:

```
t="Python 2.7.0"
if echo "$(python -V 2>&1)"$'\n'"$t" | sort -V -k2,2 | head -n1 | grep -q "$t"
then
    echo "version greater than $t"
fi
```

Since GNU `sort -V` is designed to handle version numbers natively, this is the approach that I prefer.